# NGX Pie Charts taking only half the space of parent div

Tags: css, angular, ngx-charts

[image]

Ngx Pie Chart takes half the allocated for example parent div is (500 , 300) takes only (250 , 150). Hence it looks smaller when put in a larger width div.

[image]

This graph is generated from canvasJs it occupies parent div height when compared to NGX Charts. Need to make look like this